# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sql-delete, pydantic

When I implemented delete method, it's giving this error. Can anyone help me?

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.int' is not mapped
```

I tried to delete a data from database but it returns an error from sqlalchemy.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, status
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List
from database import engine, SessionLocal
from models import Blog, User
from fastapi import HTTPException
import schemas,models

app = FastAPI()

def getdb():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close

models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine) #migrating

@app.get('/blog')
def all_blogs(db: Session = Depends(getdb)):
    db_blog = db.query(Blog).all()
    return db_blog

@app.get('/user')
def all_users(db: Session = Depends(getdb)):
    db_blog= db.query(User).all()
    return db_blog

@app.post('/blog', status_code= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_blog(blog: schemas.BlogCreate, db: Session = Depends(getdb)):
    db_blog = Blog(title=blog.title, user_id = blog.user_id)
    db.add(db_blog)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_blog)
    return db_blog


@app.post('/user', status_code= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(getdb)):
    db_user = User(name = user.name)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user

@app.delete('/blog/{blog_id}', status_code= status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
def destroy(blog_id, db:Session = Depends(getdb)):
    db_blog = db.query(Blog).filter(Blog.id == blog_id).delete(synchronize_session="evaluate")
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_blog)
    return f"{Blog.id} deleted"


@app.get('/blog/{blog_id}', response_model=schemas.Blog)
def show_blog(blog_id: int, db: Session = Depends(getdb)):
    db_blog = db.query(Blog).filter(Blog.id == blog_id).first()
    if not db_blog:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Blog not found')
    return db_blog

@app.get('/user/{user_id}', response_model=schemas.User)
def show_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(getdb)):
    db_user = db.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
    if not db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Blog not found')
    return db_user
```

Answer (score 0):

[Calling `delete` on an ORM query result returns an int](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.delete) - the number of rows deleted.

Since you're using that value as `db_blog`, and then trying to refresh *that value* from the session, that will fail - an int isn't bound to the session at all.

```py
db_blog = db.query(Blog).filter(Blog.id == blog_id).delete(synchronize_session="evaluate")
^^^^^^^ - this is an int

db.refresh(db_blog)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this fails, since `db_blog` is an int and not an ORM object.
```

Generally the relevant contents of the session will expire after the request has finished regardless, or when you're calling `commit`:

> When the COMMIT operation is complete, all objects are fully expired, erasing their internal contents, which will be automatically re-loaded when the objects are next accessed.